# rails forms base error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Reading from the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#errors-base) it says to change the base error message you can append what your new base to the errors array. For some reason doing so result in two error messages rather one and does not even do what I expected, This is what I have in my code

```
validates :tawme, :start_date, presence: true
def tawme
  errors[:base] << "Buyaka!"
end
```

However when there is an error message on the form I get

```
The form contains 2 errors
Buyaka!
Start date can't be blank
```

I was expecting that `"Start date"` would be replaced with `"Buyaka!"` since that is the new base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove :start_date from method arguments and add a call to `if start_date.blank?` in the method tawme like this...

```
validate :tawme
def tawme
  errors[:base] << "Buyaka!" if start_date.blank?
end
```

Note the removed 's' as per Rails validation method. `validates` becomes `validate`.

In your code, you still included a validates_presence_of(start_date).

Furthermore, errors[:base] is an array WHICH YOU ARE NOT REPLACING.

The `<<` method pushes the string on to the end of the array in the `errors` hash.

Helpful...
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods

Comment: right, you are REPLACING the beginning of the array with the new custom message :-)

Comment: No you are appending to it. If you have pry, which you should, and inserted a before validate block with a call to binding.pry, you can type errors into the command line, getting back the hash which has a [:base] and [:start_date] array. You can add stuff to it. Try typing errors[:base] << "Hello there." and then display the has again. You will then have "Buyaka" and "Hello there" next to each other.

Comment: Ruby doc on the `<<` method. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C

Comment: Actually you are right about your point, thanks for the clarification